# Shopping cart always "empty" after 1.9.3.4 upgrade

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, cart, addtocart, form-key

I have upgraded magento to 1.9.3.4 via magento connect from 1.9.3.3 and now whenever I try to add a product to the cart it says shopping cart empty.
I added `<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>`  to all the form sections recommended to my theme (intenso theme) but that didnt work so I tested with both RWD and default themes and both of those behave the same and show cart as empty.

I have checked that `<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>` is in the form sections of both RWD and default themes and it is,so that is not the problem.

I have tried with both formkey validation on and off in the settings and get the same result. Ordering worked before on version 1.9.3.3.

I have cookie lifetime set to 86400, have tried different cookie domain settings and the cookie path is /

Im not sure what to try next as reading through other posts with the same problem they are all resolved by adding `<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>` to the relevent forms.

Comment: Open your browsers developer tools and check your `frontend` cookie before and after adding to cart.  I want to make sure that your session is staying consistent.

Comment: I cleared cookies, tried a cart add with dev tools. There was just 1 single frontend cookie created throughout the process. The cookie was from .mydomain.com (I have cookie domain setting to this) and the url of the site is new.mydomain.com (currently a dev site). Not sure if that effects anything - ive tried clearing the cookie domain part out also but nothing changes.

Comment: additional - tried changing the cookie domain setting to be new.mydomain.com to test but same result

Comment: Have you tried to turn off Block Caching ? The forms might be cached server side?

Comment: I havent and currently I cannot log into admin area even now due to form key issue I have tried completed deleting the cache and session folders under var though (which are successfully recreating proving they can be written to) so that would eliminate that I would believe?

Comment: I have fixed the log into admin issue again now (used n98-magerun to disable cache, check config and deleted all cookies again). I also tried reverting to a backup of the volume I made before the 1.9.3.4 upgrade running the 1.9.3.3 version and that works for ordering. At this stage im thinking I should just stick with 1.9.3.3 as it is a minor version difference - only reason I upgrade is because its a dev site and I thought it would be easy and best to start off on latest version.